# unknown method 'opportunity.save()'

Tags: visualforce

I am new in salesforce development.I am started learning visualforce. Please help to resolve this issue.

**Vf page :**

```xml
<apex:page controller="UpdateOpportunity">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity_list">
            
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OpptyDetail}" var = "opporty">
                <apex:inputField value = "{!opporty.Name}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value = "{!opporty.StageName}"/>    
                
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class:**

```java
public class UpdateOpportunity {
    public List<Opportunity> getOpptyDetail(){
        List<Opportunity> opptylist =[SELECT Id,Name,StageName FROM opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Prospecting'];
        return opptylist;
        
    }
}
```

It's thrown error:`Unknown method UpdateOpportunity.Save()`

Comment: you need to add a `PageReference save() {..do the DML}` method in the custom controller as Hengky stated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to go through this trailhead [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals) to get started with Visualforce.

To answer your question, your Visualforce page is using Custom Controller. So in order for your code to work, you must define you own `save()` method in the controller class.

Save and Cancel are standard controller methods. Unless you use standardController, it won't work.

---

Edit:
Some changes needed in your custom controller class.
You need to define a variable to hold the list of Opportunity records for update later, and implement a `save()` method to call the DML update.

```java
public class UpdateOpportunity {
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();

    public UpdateOpportunity() {
        opportunities = [SELECT Id,Name,StageName FROM opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Prospecting'];
    }

    public List<Opportunity> getOpptyDetail(){
        return opportunities;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update(opportunities);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The example above is actually very similar to [Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm).

Comment: I gone through the module but didn't get clear idea to create save() method for custom controller .Can you please explain me how to do this.

Comment: Hi Hengky, Thankyou for your help. After I tried this  got one error.  *Error:   Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!opporty.Name}'. <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.*

Comment: I saw you have accepted the answer. Did you manage to solve the issue above?

Comment: No Hengky.It throws same error

Comment: That's weird because I tried with the same code, it worked for me. Btw, in your vfpage, since you use apex:pageBlockTable you need to put the inputfield inside an apex:column tag.